# PostgreSQL Inserting 2 relationships at once

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables `professionals`, `services`, and `feature_professional` I need to insert data into when inserting a `professional`. This is the sql I've tried.

```
WITH professionals as (INSERT INTO professionals(id, company_id, first_name) 
VALUES (1, 1, 'peter') RETURNING *) 

INSERT INTO services(id, professional_id, name) 
VALUES (1, (select professionals.id from professionals), 'haircut'),

INSERT INTO feature_professional(id, professional_id, feature_id, enabled) 
VALUES
    (1, (select professionals.id from professionals), 1, true)
```

I've also tried different variations of this wrapping all the insert statements inside parenthesis but still no luck. The error I'm getting is a `syntax error`.

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INSERT"
LINE 106: INSERT INTO feature_professional
```

What is the correct syntax to accomplish this? I know that if I take out the third `insert` statement the query works. For example:

```
WITH professionals as (INSERT INTO professionals(id, company_id, first_name) 
VALUES (1, 1, 'peter') RETURNING *) 

INSERT INTO services(id, professional_id, name) 
VALUES (1, (select professionals.id from professionals), 'haircut')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant do two insert after a cte, so wrap each one in a different cte

**[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f5174/3)**

```
WITH professionals as (
    INSERT INTO professionals(id, company_id, first_name) 
    VALUES (1, 1, 'peter') RETURNING *
), 
services as (
    INSERT INTO services(id, professional_id, name) 
    VALUES (1, (select professionals.id from professionals), 'haircut')
)
INSERT INTO features(id, professional_id, name) 
VALUES (1, (select professionals.id from professionals), 'autobook');

select * from professionals;
select * from services;
select * from features;
```

Comment: If I do 2 cte statements with an insert inside of them isn't that going to create 2 records in the DB?

Comment: I never did insert in a cte before so I try on this [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/23e05/2) but after insert the table doesnt show any the inserted rows. Is this how should work?

Comment: This works and this is essentially what I have in my app right now. [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/23e05/9).

Comment: When I add the third table into the mix that's when the issues start happening. [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/f5174/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO feature_professional (id, professional_id, feature_id, enabled) 
select ?, professionals.id from professionals, ?, ?
```

Provided that the question marks are values you can insert.  If they aren't required you can just omit them.

```
INSERT INTO feature_professional (professional_id) 
select professionals.id from professionals
```

Here is how to insert from a select instead of static values:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: I don't know if this makes sense but the issue I'm having is with running those 3 queries in 1 query. I confident the actual insert statements are correct, just how I'm using 3 of them in one query is incorrect